# ExtJS: Issue updating HTML on bound form

Tags: extjs, binding

Please refer to the following fiddle: [Binding HTML Issue](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/24eq&view/editor)

When you select a row from the combobox on the left panel, it prints the bound value, along with some HTML in the form on right. When you then click on the button labeled as 'Test Update' it first clears the bound value in the drop down, and then is supposed to update the HTML to clear it, as well.

Problem is, that the update for the `displayfield` referenced in the `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` does not work in this order. If I do the update first in the fiddle it works, but if I try this in my actual app, it does not (in my app the `setValue` on the `combobox` DOES work though, but then leaves the HTML label - which I want to clear).

An ideas as to why this behavior is occurring would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would want to use a formula for that, it simplifies the logic behind it.

```
viewModel: {
    formulas: {
        foo: function(get) {
            var sel = get('peopleComboRef.selection');

            return sel ? ('HTML Label: ' + sel.get('name')) : '';
        }
    }
},
```

then bind this formula to your `displayfield`.

```
{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    itemId: 'displayTest',
    bind:  {
        html: '{foo}'
    }
}
```

fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/24f5&view/editor

Comment: Sweet! I hadn't even thought about use of formulas.